# JavaFX Menu (not MenuItem) with ToolTip?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

is there any possibility to add a Tooltip to a JavaFX (Sub-)Menu?

The usual (but ugly - why can't a menu not just be made of nodes?!) solution for MenuItems is to use a CustomMenuItem and put a Label (which is a Node) in it - the label can be assigned a ToolTip.

But how can I achieve this for a (Sub-)Menu? See the following example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomSubMenu extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Menu");

        Label helloLabel = new Label("Hello...");
        helloLabel.tooltipProperty().setValue(new Tooltip("World!"));
        menuButton.getItems().add(new CustomMenuItem(helloLabel));


        Menu submenu = new Menu("This Submenu needs a ToolTip!");
        //             new CustomMenuItem(new Menu()); // doesn't work, because Menu is not a Node.
        submenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Some other Item"));
        menuButton.getItems().add(submenu);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(menuButton));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each menuItem (and naturally also a menu) is associated with a node. That node is accessible after the item has been shown at least once. Then the node is accessible via `item.getStyleableNode()` (since fx9, for fx8 see below) and a tooltip can be set on that node.

So basically, the way to go is to listen for that instant and then install a tooltip. The example below does so by

- create a tooltip for the menu/item and put it into its properties
- register a onShown handler on the parent menu and install the tooltip if available

A basic snippet:

```
String tooltipKey = "TOOL_TIP";
MenuItem normalItem = new MenuItem("Good .. ");
normalItem.getProperties().put(tooltipKey, new Tooltip("Morning!"));
menuButton.getItems().add(normalItem);
Menu submenu = new Menu("This Submenu needs a ToolTip!");
submenu.getProperties().put(tooltipKey, new Tooltip("It's meee!"));
menuButton.setOnShown(e -> {
    menuButton.getItems().forEach(item -> {
        Node node = item.getStyleableNode();
        if (node != null && item.getProperties().get(tooltipKey) instanceof Tooltip) {
            Tooltip tip = (Tooltip) item.getProperties().get(tooltipKey);
            Tooltip.install(node, tip);
        }
    });

});
```

---

For fx8, the basic approach is the same - but access to the node that represents the menuItem is nasty (beware: don't in production! *cough ..):

- getStyleableNode is new to fx9, so we have to hack around using internal api and implementation details
- the time at which the node is available is harder to find: the obvious hook would be an eventHandler for SHOWN on the menuButton, but that doesn't seem to be supported (doesn't seem to be supported yet - didn't dig though)
- one way around is to first listen to the showingProperty, grab the contextMenu, listen to its skinProperty and do the install once the skin is set

code snippets:

```
// not working - what's wrong?
menuButton.addEventHandler(MenuButton.ON_SHOWN, e -> {
    LOG.info("not getting here?");
    // install tooltips here
});

ChangeListener<Skin> skinListener = (src, ov, skin) -> {
    ContextMenuContent content = (ContextMenuContent) skin.getNode();
    VBox menuBox = (VBox) content.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
    menuBox.getChildren().forEach(node -> {
        // implementation detail: the menuItem is set in the node's properties
        if (node.getProperties().get(MenuItem.class) instanceof MenuItem) {
            MenuItem item = (MenuItem) node.getProperties().get(MenuItem.class);
            if (node != null && item.getProperties().get(tooltipKey) instanceof Tooltip) {
                Tooltip tip = (Tooltip) item.getProperties().get(tooltipKey);
                Tooltip.install(node, tip);
            }

        }

    });
};
menuButton.showingProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv) -> {
    ContextMenu popup = submenu.getParentPopup();
    if (popup != null) {
        if (popup.getSkin() == null) {
            popup.skinProperty().addListener(skinListener);
        } else {
            popup.skinProperty().removeListener(skinListener);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, kleopatra!
but it seems as if getStyleableNode was added with java 9 - unfortunately, I'm stuck with java 8 at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simple way to trick the **MenuItem** as a Control **Label** node, use code like below:

```
    Label lb=new Label("MenuItem Text");
    lb.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:black;");
    MenuItem myMenuItem = new MenuItem(null, lb);
    Tooltip tips = new Tooltip("Your tip text here");   
    Tooltip.install(myMenuItem.getGraphic(), tips);
```

set the tooltip to the label and this works pretty good for me.

Comment: For Menu,  the same trick works as well.  i.e. use Menu mu=new Menu(null, new Label("MenuName") ).